# Simple solution for maximum product?

Tags: calculus, optimization, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

The sum of $3$ and $7$ is $10~ (3 + 7 = 10)$ and the product of $3$ and $7$ is $21~ (3 \times 7 = 21)$. Similarly, $2.1 + 3.2 + 4.7 = 10$ and $2.1 \times 3.2 \times 4.7 = 31.584$.

What is the largest product that can be made from numbers that sum to $10$?

Clearly, this problem is solvable with basic calculus but there should be an easier solution (this was asked in a high school math competition) but I can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using AM-GM, for $n$ terms the maximum is when each term is the same, to get a product of $(10/n)^n$.

This in turn is maximised when $n=4$.. to get $2.5^4= 39.0625$, the function is unimodal, so you could use calculus and try integers nearest to the optimum real number. Or you could track ratios of successive terms and find the maximum without calculus - that would be more cumbersome though.

Comment: How do you know it is maximized then? I did same thing with derivative. Any easier ways?

Comment: Read up on the Arithmetic Mean $\ge$ Geometric mean inequality.  AM can equal GM only when the terms are all equal, so that is when the product attains maximum.

Comment: `find the maximum without calculus` In the time it takes to find a clever non-calculus solution, one could simply note that $(10/n)^n \le 1$ for $n \ge 10$ then find the maximum by hand for $2 \le n \le 9$.

Answer (score 0):

Any number $n$ that is $5$ or larger can be replaced by $3$ and $n-3$, so there are no numbers larger than $4$.  You might as well replace $4$ by $2,2$, so you will only have $2$s and $3$s.  As $3,3$ beats $2,2,2$ you should have zero, one, or two $2$s.  For the specific case of $10$, you do best with $2,2,3,3$ with product $36$